# Save WebResponse as excel to server

Tags: excel, screen-scraping, httpwebresponse

I need to save the response which is of content type "application/vnd.ms-excel" as excel to the server with random file name. I am using the following code to get the response through screen scrapping and i need to save it as excel to my server path.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(postData);
writer.Close();
try
{
   responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

   //Save the response as Excel to the server
   string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch
{
}
```

Please suggest to save the response as excel to the server path